# How to override processForm() in admin-generator

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I'm trying to add some extra logic to `update` and `delete` actions in a module generated by task `doctrine:generate-admin`. I read [here](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/jobeet/1_2/en/12?orm=Doctrine) and see that I can create `executeUpdate()` and `executeDelete()` methods in `/application/mymodule/actions/actions.class.php`. Because `executeUpdate()` call `proccessForm()` method then I think the best is to override this instead of `executeUpdate()` but don't know how. The code I need to add is this:

```
$q = Doctrine_Core::getTable('SdrivingEmpresa')
            ->createQuery('a')
            ->where('idempresa = ?', $request->getParameter('idempresa'))
            ->execute();
$file = new sfFilesystem();
$file->remove(sfConfig::get('sf_upload_dir') . '/' . $q[0]->getLogotipo());
```

I do it for `executeDelete()` by copying the generated cache coded and writing my logic see below:

```
public function executeDelete(sfWebRequest $request) {
    $request->checkCSRFProtection();
    $this->dispatcher->notify(new sfEvent($this, 'admin.delete_object', array('object' => $this->getRoute()->getObject())));

    $q = Doctrine_Core::getTable('SdrivingEmpresa')
            ->createQuery('a')
            ->where('idempresa = ?', $request->getParameter('idempresa'))
            ->execute();
    $file = new sfFilesystem();
    $file->remove(sfConfig::get('sf_upload_dir') . '/' . $q[0]->getLogotipo());

    if ($this->getRoute()->getObject()->delete()) {
        $this->getUser()->setFlash('notice', 'The item was deleted successfully.');
    }
    $this->redirect('@sdriving_empresa');
}
```

But I tough this is not right, so my question is, should I do the same with processForm() or exists a better way to do this? any advice or help?

Comment: You should use the lifecycle events available on your model objects. You can add functions like `preDelete`, `postDelete`, `preUpdate`, `postUpdate`, `preSave`, `postSave`, `preInsert`, `postInsert`. You can add there any logic which should be associated with the given event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy the `proccessForm()` generated in the cache of the application in your admin module action to override it.